# HQL : max/limit result based on property value

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have a domain, AccountTransaction

```
class AccountTransaction {
  Account account
  BigDecimal amount
  ...
}
```

I would like to get the maximum last 3 transactions of each account.
Output expected:

```
id  | account | amount
______________________
1   | a1      | 200
21  | a1      | 300
33  | a1      | 100
11  | a2      | 100
22  | a2      | 30
31  | a2      | 10
55  | a3      | 20
```

How should I write HQL/Criteria query for the same? Is it really supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some column date_created to work with the lastest transactions

SQL:

```
select id, account, amount
from account_transaction as at1
where (
   select count(*) from account_transaction as at2
   where at1.account_id = at2.account_id and at1.date_created < at2.date_created
) <= 2;
```

HQL:

```
AccountTransaction.executeQuery("select id, account, amount from AccountTransaction as at1
where (select count(*) from AccountTransaction as at2 
where at1.account = at2.account and at1.date_created > at2.date_created) <= 2")
```

Comment: Thanks a million! it just worked. Just used id instead of dateCreated i.e at1.id < at2.id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to use HQL/Criteria to get this:

```
AccountTransaction.list(max: 3, sort: 'amount', order: 'desc')
```

Comment: That will give three entries with the highest amount. But he will a list with three entries with the highest amount for each account.